# why there are meaningless asm code in gcc "start" function (before main)?

Tags: gcc, assembly, llvm

I  am a bit interested in what does the run time do, so I write a simple c program like below.(I do not paste the code of some_function. I think it's not important.)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    some_fucntion();
    return;
}
```

I use i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 on my Mac(10.6.8, Intel Core) and compiler the source with following command. Actually I have tried to use O3 and get same result.

```
gcc -O0 -o test test.c
```

Then I type following command and get those asm code.

```
otool -tV test
```

I get the following asm code. I guess those code relates to prepare the arguments for main function. But I still can't figure out why there are a loop to set eax to 0x00? And why there are a "jmp" instruction? so the next instruction will never be executed, right?

I would be really appreciate if anyone could explain the whole asm code here. Thanks.

```
start:
0000000100000d20        pushq   $0x00
0000000100000d22        movq    %rsp,%rbp
0000000100000d25        andq    $0xf0,%rsp
0000000100000d29        movq    0x08(%rbp),%rdi
0000000100000d2d        leaq    0x10(%rbp),%rsi
0000000100000d31        movl    %edi,%edx
0000000100000d33        addl    $0x01,%edx
0000000100000d36        shll    $0x03,%edx
0000000100000d39        addq    %rsi,%rdx
0000000100000d3c        movq    %rdx,%rcx
0000000100000d3f        jmp     0x100000d45
0000000100000d41        addq    $0x08,%rcx
0000000100000d45        cmpq    $0x00,(%rcx)
0000000100000d49        jne     0x100000d41
0000000100000d4b        addq    $0x08,%rcx
0000000100000d4f        callq   _main
0000000100000d54        movl    %eax,%edi
0000000100000d56        callq   0x100000e7c     ; symbol stub for: _exit
0000000100000d5b        hlt
0000000100000d5c        nop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
start:
0000000100000d20        pushq   $0x00               ; push NULL (end of dynamic frame pointer chain)
0000000100000d22        movq    %rsp,%rbp           ; set frame pointer
0000000100000d25        andq    $0xf0,%rsp          ; align stack
0000000100000d29        movq    0x08(%rbp),%rdi     ; mov argc to 1st arg
0000000100000d2d        leaq    0x10(%rbp),%rsi     ; mov argv to 2nd arg
0000000100000d31        movl    %edi,%edx           ; \
0000000100000d33        addl    $0x01,%edx          ; > 3rd arg = argv + (argc + 1) * 8
0000000100000d36        shll    $0x03,%edx          ; > = envp
0000000100000d39        addq    %rsi,%rdx           ; /
0000000100000d3c        movq    %rdx,%rcx           ; \
0000000100000d3f        jmp     0x100000d45         ; >
0000000100000d41        addq    $0x08,%rcx          ; > find 1st NULL after envp and
0000000100000d45        cmpq    $0x00,(%rcx)        ; > move to 4th arg
0000000100000d49        jne     0x100000d41         ; /
0000000100000d4b        addq    $0x08,%rcx          ; and add 8 (apple)
0000000100000d4f        callq   _main               ; call main
0000000100000d54        movl    %eax,%edi           ; move return value to 1st arg
0000000100000d56        callq   0x100000e7c         ; and call _exit (doesn't return)
0000000100000d5b        hlt
0000000100000d5c        nop
```

`apple` is an Apple-specific argument that contains the path to the executable ([source](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2006/02/char-apple-argument-vector.html)).

Comment: Thanks, however I am not sure why there are four arguments for main function. I only know 3 of them: argc,argv and envp. Could you please tell me what's the fourth one? Or the fourth one is only used for return value of main function? And how could we know 0x08(%rbp) is argc instead of agrv? @ninjalj,could you add some reference links so I could gain more.

Comment: It was `apple`, not `auxv`: I was thinking of ELF, not Mac OS X (Mach-O?). And about `0x08(%rbp)`, `(%rbp)` contains the previous frame pointer (NULL in this case, we are the end of the chain), and `0x8(%ebp)` contains the first argument.